# jQuery File Upload plugin with webpack $(...).fileupload is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using Rails 6, and I need to use jquery file upload plugin, I would like to add manually instead of using yarn, so I downloaded this file here: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.31.0/js/jquery.fileupload.js  and put it into `app/javascript` folder

then in `app/javascript/packs/application.js` I added the line

```
require("jquery.fileupload")
```

In my `app/javascript/main.js` :

```
$('#file-input').fileupload()
```

I get the error :

```
TypeError: $(...).fileupload is not a function
```

If I put `$('#file-input').fileupload()` in `javascript/packs/application.js` like this :

```
require("jquery.fileupload")
$('#file-input').fileupload()
```

The error disappear ! so the issue seems to be that the plugin can only be accessed in application.js and not in other files, how I can solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

I lost 2 or 3 hours trying use webpack without success.

Then simple download `*.js` files directly from blueimp repository to `app/javascript/packs/vendor` and import it in `application.js`.

Comment: I understand... I was in the same situation before, I wrote a blog post about webpack here https://medium.com/p/e3534fded7ff which you may find helpful, if you have any question let me know